# Wordpress Admin - create page filter by meta_key

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I use plugin Advanced Custom Fields but I want create page in admin when will filter by metakey.

I know how create page for post type but it's not the same.

My code in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'init', 'event' );

function event() {
  register_post_type( 'event', array(
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => 'Events',
      'singular_name' => 'event',
     ),
    'description' => 'Events',
    'public' => true,
    'menu_position' => 20,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt'),
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'event'),
    'has_archive'=>false,
    'taxonomies'=>['category'],
  ));
}
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you want. Do you mean you need a page which can be filtered by meta_key, such as manage-posts-page ?

Can you provide a puedo code or some visual reference ?

Comment: Yes, I want shows all pages when meta_key = event (example).

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for either. You need to update your question to clarify exactly what you want to achieve. Can you explain whats the difference between this and a custom post type for example?

Answer (score 0):

If you add some meta fields to some post type all posts will has that field. You could filter posts by not empty meta fields using following code:

```
    $args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'page',
    'meta_key'   => 'event',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

OR if you want to filter by value of this meta field you should use `meta_query`:

```
    $args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'page',
    'meta_key'   => 'event',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'event',
            'value'   => array( 'party', 'wedding' ),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Read more on this page - https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query